# Magento: New products on category page is not sorting by position

Tags: php, sorting, magento, magento-1.7, categories

I am working on magento category page. I just added a product in a category and that product showing in frontend fine. but not getting sort by position, all type of sorting is fine, but when  i sort according to position. New product show always on first position. and old products comes according to position fine. Also descending order is not working in position.
I have deleted cache, re-indexed also.
Can anyone suggest what's the problem.

Comment: You have problem just with new products? How do you set products position in category? Also this post may help you [Changing default category sort order in Magento] (http://inchoo.net/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/)

Comment: I set position as ...catalog > manage categories > select that category > go to category products tab and there is option to add position for specific product.

Comment: I have already seen that link, In this page it is showing that how to change default order, but my problem is something different from it,

Comment: Do you have any theme? If yes, switch to default rwd theme and test it.

Comment: I haven't installed any theme too.

Comment: Check this file then /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml line 54 to 69. Also try to reindex from shell by going to /shell directory then `php indexer.php --reindexall`

Comment: I have done this too

Answer (score 0):

Did you set product position value in `Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Category Products` tab? In `position` column you should set position for each product.

Comment: I have set the position for each products